# Is it possible to develop themes and plugins locally while still allowing content to be updated directly in the admin dashboard?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

Any similar questions that I've found asked specifically about setting up local environments and/or setting up version control. They never ask whether it's possible to have a development workflow for themes and plugins while still allowing non-technical users to modify content directly on a web server using the admin dashboard.

I'm new to WordPress...is it possible to deploy only the files required to update themes and plugins and not overwrite new content on the server?

I feel these big companies using WordPress must have found a way to enable both release management processes and quick content updates using the admin dashboard.

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: Hi Ben, welcome to StackOverflow. Good question. Do you mean, when you are done developing theme(s) or plugin(s) locally, you want to push just the code to the server without messing with the database/content of the production server? Or do you mean, you want to develop locally but use database/content from production server online?

Comment: I'd suggest installing another copy of wordpress in a password protected subfolder which only you can access. You can also export your existing database, import it with a different name and work with existing data. In my honest opinion playing the development game on a production site is always a bad idea. There are tools which will backup your existing site which could be restored into a new site, thereby giving you what you currently have.

Comment: @Junaid, yes to your first question, I'd like to enable developers to develop locally and have their code deployed to any environment, while keeping any content that was added/modified directly on the server.

Comment: @AdmiralNoisyBottom, I agree that doing anything on a production site sounds like a bad idea. Nonetheless, management is looking for an expedient solution at the moment. Do you know if medium/large companies have their content writers use the admin dashboard or do enterprise implementations of WordPress generally lock that down?

Comment: @BenWolski Being a small time wordpress webhost, as I am, I'd imagine the larger sites have content writers use their dashboards much like average users. Perhaps they write their content in a word processor and import in large quantities into sites. I really don't have an answer for that as I've never been medium or large :)